# Set thread name for boost logger

Tags: c++, multithreading, logging, boost

I'm trying to set readable name to thread for the Boost logger instead of hex thread id. Here is how it looks now:

```
sink->set_formatter(
boost::log::expressions::stream << std::setw(5) << 
boost::log::expressions::attr <unsigned int>("LineID")
<< " [" << boost::log::expressions::format_date_time <boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%H:%M:%S.%f")
<< "] <" << boost::log::expressions::attr <Severity_Level>("Severity") 
<< "> (" << boost::log::expressions::attr <boost::log::attributes::current_thread_id::value_type> ("ThreadID")
<< ") " << boost::log::expressions::smessage);
```

My first thought was to make a map container or to use pthread_setname_np somehow. But the problem is how to insert this into boost logging structure. Is there any way to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a thread-specific attribute with the thread name.

```
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(a_thread_name, "ThreadName", std::string)

void thread_entry()
{
    boost::log::core::get()->add_thread_attribute("ThreadName",
        boost::log::attributes::constant< std::string >("My thread name"));

    // Your thread logic follows
}
```

This is typically done in your thread startup function.

You can use this attribute in filters and formatters the same way as any other attribute. For example:

```
sink->set_formatter(
    boost::log::expressions::stream << std::setw(5) << 
    boost::log::expressions::attr <unsigned int>("LineID")
    << " [" << boost::log::expressions::format_date_time <boost::posix_time::ptime>("TimeStamp", "%H:%M:%S.%f")
    << "] <" << boost::log::expressions::attr <Severity_Level>("Severity") 
    << "> (" << boost::log::expressions::attr <boost::log::attributes::current_thread_id::value_type> ("ThreadID")
    << ", " << a_thread_name
    << ") " << boost::log::expressions::smessage);
```

You can learn more about [thread-specific attributes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/design.html#log.design.attributes_and_attribute_values), [attribute keywords](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/expressions.html#log.detailed.expressions.attr_keywords) and [`constant` attribute](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/attributes.html#log.detailed.attributes.constant) from the docs.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I need!

Comment: Oh! And one little question, since you are boost log developer as I understand. I want to make boost_log_function for all functions in the project to add them to named scope. Is it possible to set something global? Or i have to set boost_log_function() for every function?

Comment: You'll have to explicitly mark every function or scope you want to see in logs; there's no option to make it implicit or automatically added by the compiler. Maybe your IDE can help with that, if you're used to its refactoring/coding services.